# Handbrake Video Encode Tool File Preview Location

Tags: video, editing, rendering, handbrake

So I added a file to render.
I didn't put destination folder.
Then i clicked preview and it started to render. After the it done rendering it open my video in VLC.

I watched it and i closed it.
So how do i delete that file? Where is it located?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer, it was pretty simple, i was looking at `%appdata%` and `temp` folder for preview rendered video.

I found the preview rendered video in video folder...

```
C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Videos
```

But not sure about one thing. I preview rendered the video file 7 or 10 times, but i only found one video called `FILENAME-9.mkv`.